# Change the target of a linked video causes the trim function stop working

Tags: c#, office-interop, powerpoint-2007

I am changing the target video in a linked video in PowerPoint 2010, but the problem comes when the original video was trimmed using the trim function so since I am just changing the target video it makes sense that the trim function still there after the relink, but is gone, and I need to keep the trim in the video shape.
 My code looks like:

`Newfile= "\\newvideo.avi";`
`Shape.LinkFormat.SourceFullName = newfile;`
`Shape.Name = Path.GetFileName(newfile);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shape's .MediaFormat object will give you the .StartPoint and .EndPoint (ie, trim points).

Pick those up before changing the link and reapply them after; I think that should solve the problem.